# Add a command output to a file from ansible lineinfile module

Tags: module, ansible

I'm trying to write a ansible task to incorporate the output of below command into /etc/lvm/lvm.conf file:

```
[root@ansible]# vgs --noheadings -o vg_name
  my_vg        
  rhel_home
  rhel_root
```

The above mentioned values need to be added as below:

```
volume_list = [ "rhel_root", "rhel_home", "my_vg" ]
```

In the managed nodes, the above paramater will be as below:

```
# volume_list = [ "vg1", "vg2/lvol1", "@tag1", "@*" ]
```

Kindly help me to proceed further as I'm stuck here:

```
- name: Fetch the Volume group
  shell: "vgs --noheadings -o vg_name"
  register: vgs

- debug:
    msg: "{{ vgs.stdout }}"

- name: Line in file
  lineinfile:
    path: /tmp/lvm.conf
    regex: "volume_list = .*"
    line: "volume_list = [ vgs.stdout_lines ]"
```

It is adding a line as below, without double quotes in the vg name:
volume_list = [ vgs.stdout_lines ]
at the bottom and not replacing the below line:

## volume_list = [ "vg1", "vg2/lvol1", "@tag1", "@*" ]

Need assistance to get output as
volume_list = [ "rhel_root", "rhel_home", "my_vg" ]

Comment: You should be looking at `vgs.stdout_lines` because *that is the list* of VG names returned by command.

Comment: I tried below task: 
```   
- name: Line in file
    lineinfile:
      path: /tmp/lvm.conf
      regex: "# volume_list = .*"
      line: "\tvolume_list = \[ \"vgs.stdout_lines\" \]"
``` 
but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your purpose, you need to use the `{{ vgs.stdout_lines }}` list (not `\"vgs.stdout_lines\"` string) variable in your `lineinfile` task.

Like:

```yaml
line: "volume_list = {{ vgs.stdout_lines | to_json }}"
```

Though, I noticed that the VG Names returned by command have preceding whitespace like  `"  rhel_root"`. So it might be a good idea to `set_fact` another variable which has the unnecessary whitespace `trim`med.

```yaml
    - command: vgs --noheadings -o vg_name
      register: vgs

    - set_fact:
        volume_list: "{{ volume_list | default([]) + [ item | trim ] }}"
      loop: "{{ vgs.stdout_lines }}"

    - lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/lvm.conf
        regexp: '# volume_list ='
        line: 'volume_list = {{ volume_list | to_json }}'
```

Comment: Thank you for the support, I need slight modification the expected ouput will have space before and after the first and last item in the list like this[ "rhel_root", "rhel_home", "my_vg" ] but we get like this ["rhel_root", "rhel_home", "my_vg"]

Comment: Tried with below one but still not able to add a space before and after the list: "volume_list = {{ ' '+ volume_list  | to_json +' ' }}"

Comment: Space should not be mandatory, do you know if the configuration doesn't work without spaces?

Comment: Thanks, as you mentioned the space is not necessary.